# Are Samsung B-Die and C-Die Compatible?

Tags: memory, network-attached-storage, truenas

I am building a NAS (running TrueNAS/FreeNAS) using a SuperMicro [A2SDi-8C+-HLN4F](https://www.supermicro.com/en/products/motherboard/A2SDi-8C+-HLN4F) motherboard. I ordered 2 sticks of this [Samsung C-Die RAM](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M393A2K40CB1-CRC/) from a supplier but they could only send me 1 as it was the last they had in stock. I ordered the same RAM from another supplier but instead received this [Samsung B-Die RAM](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/dram/module/M393A2K40BB1-CRC/). I found out this was not a mistake as the C-Die is EOL and the B-Die is its replacement.

While it's not ideal to have two unmatched sticks of RAM in dual-channel mode, the specs according to the datasheets are 99% identical. Do I have anything to be worried about?

Comment: to be honestly i never thought about such as detail, i belive it happens more often as every spoken about, since i also can use different vendors with same size i think it doesnt make sense to think about, but good question anyways-

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These sticks are identical enough that you can freely mix and match them in a server and they should correctly go multi-channel. All of the [relevant specs](https://www.samsung.com/semiconductor/global.semi/file/resource/2018/06/DDR4_Product_guide_May.18.pdf) are identical between them.

Virtually everything you will find about the differences will be on Internet forums about overclocking, where it is generally agreed that B-die chips overclock higher and more stably than C-die chips. It's unlikely that you will be doing any overclocking.

Comment: Thank you, that's good to hear. Yeah, I will definitely not be doing any overclocking on the system. Not even sure if this BIOS allows it. Thanks for the input!